# char to int conversion

Tags: java, char, int

So I have something like this:

```
char cr = "9783815820865".charAt(0);
System.out.println(cr);   //prints out 9
```

If I do this:

```
 int cr = "9783815820865".charAt(0);
 System.out.println(cr);   //prints out 57
```

I understand that the conversion between char and int is not simply from `'9'` to `9`. My problem is right now I simply need to keep the 9 as the int value, not 57. How to get the value 9 instead of 57 as a `int` type?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try with:

```
int cr = "9783815820865".charAt(0) - '0';
```

`charAt(0)` will return `'9'` (as a `char`), which is a numeric type. From this value we'll just subtract the value of `'0'`, which is again numeric and is exactly nine entries behind the entry of the `'9'` character in the ASCII table.

So, behind the scenes, the the subtraction will work with the ASCII codes of `'9'` and `'0'`, which means that `57 - 48` will be calculated.

Comment: please elaborate why it works? I just tried and works, but don't know why

Comment: because in the ascii table the, characters from 0-9 is in increasing order. so if I want to get the raw integer value of a character, let's say '9', in the ascii table '9' integer representation would be a number like 57 but if we minus that by characters '0' which is stored as a number, 48, we will get 9, see for yourself 57-48 is equal to 9.

Answer (score 5):

try this:

```
char c = "9783815820865".charAt(0);
int cr = Integer.parseInt(c+"");
```

Comment: this does not work? have you tried? The type char cannot convert to int.

Comment: eclipse, it does not work for me. if it works for u please attach a screenshot.

Comment: please try this, if that doesn't work for you:
char c = "9783815820865".charAt(0);
String s = "" + c;
int cr = Integer.parseInt(s);

Comment: just needed a little adjustement.... check [working demo here](https://ideone.com/TPPo0v)

Comment: Thanks @JordiCastilla

Comment: please accept the answer @JasonZ if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`Character#getNumericValue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue-char-) may be more idiomatic.  Bear in mind that it'll convert anything above `'A'` as 10.

```
int cr = Character.getNumericValue("9783815820865".charAt(0));
System.out.println(cr);
```