# How can an int be declared with ' ' and why is '2' == 50?

Tags: java, arrays, char, int

Question is: What gets displayed in console?

And I really have some problems with understanding.

Here is the code:

```
public static void felda(){
    char[] felda = {'2',0x31,48};
    for (int i = 0; i< felda.length; i++){
        System.out.println(" : " + felda[i]);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
public static void feldb(){
    int[] feldb = {'2',0x31,48};
    for (int i = 0; i< feldb.length; i++){
        System.out.println(" : " + feldb[i]);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
public static void feldc(){
    int [] feldc = {'2',0x31,48};
    for (int i = 0; i< feldc.length; i++){
        System.out.println(" : " + (char) feldc[i]);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

So if I run in the Solution is:

```
: 2
: 1
: 0

: 50
: 49
: 48

: 2
: 1
: 0
```

So I don't understand how it is even possible to have an int definded with ' '. 
And I find it very confusing how `int feldb = '2'` results in being 50 and int feldb=0x31 results in being 49.. dam this is all so confusing. I hope someone can enlighten me.

Edit: Why is `char feldc = 48;` resulting in being 0?

Comment: http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: http://www.ascii-code.com/

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32051600/char-to-int-conversion

Answer (score 4):

In Java, a `char` represents a Unicode character. But it's also in fact an unsigned integer, on 2 bytes, which can go from 0 to 2<sup>16</sup> - 1.

So,

```
char c = '2';
```

initializes `c` with the character '2'. And the numeric value of the character '2', in Unicode, is 50.

So, if you print it as a character, '2' will be printed. If you print it as a numeric value (as an int, using `int c = '2'`), 50 will be printed.

When doing

```
char feldc = 48;
```

you initialize feldc with the character whose numeric Unicode value is 48, and that character is the character '0'. It's thus equivalent to

```
char feldc = '0';
```

`0x31` is a number written as an hexadecimal literal (that's what the `0x`prefix means). When you write `31`, the value is in decimal. It's equal to 1 * 10<sup>0</sup> + 3 * 10<sup>1</sup>.

In hexadecimal, the base is 16 rather than 10. So `0x31` is equal to 1 * 16<sup>0</sup> + 3 * 16<sup>1</sup>, which is equal to 49.

Answer (score 2):

50 is the ASCII value of the '2' character. Defined like that its not the number 2.. its giving the ASCII value of a character. See this ASCII table and find the '2' char

http://ascii.cl/index.htm?content=mobile

Comment: Technically it is not giving the ASCII value of the character, but the Unicode codepoint of the character. They just happen to be the same.